# custom columns with custom headings and fields in tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I'm trying to create the ability to add custom columns to a tabulator table.
I have a db table where I have a title and field. I extract that info into a json and want that to be added to my table.

```
    fetch("../includes/getCustomColumns.php")
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
      }).then(function(returned) {
     window.customColumns = returned
      console.log(window.customColumns)
     })
```

Then in my table I have

```
     {
        title : "Custom Columns",
        columns: [
        window.customColumns,
        ],
        }
```

But I get
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined and tabulator.min.js:2 Invalid column definition option in 'undefined' column: ..
I can see the two columns in the console log and if I copy that into the table it works. I'm wondering if it ss it even possible to add customisable columns to Tabulator or am I simply on the wrong track.

Comment: There is not enough information to go on here to provide an answer, please create a JS Fiddle that demonstrates your issue and include a link to it in your question

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the code more specifically than what you have here, I'm going to guess that because the fetch() is asynchronous, that window.customColumns is still undefined when you are creating the Tabulator. And then "sometime later" your fetch() sets the value, but it's too late.

You could use [addColumn()](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/columns#add) to programatically add the response to your fetch() when it is received.